# problem book on Functions of Two Real Variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

please refer a problem book on

**Functions of Two Real Variables**: limit, continuity, partial derivatives, **differentiability**, maxima and minima. Method of Lagrange multipliers, Homogeneous functions including Euler’s theorem.

i have already done this text from **Calculus by Thomas Finney**.But i need one problem book to solve in order to be confident to sit for my exam. I dont need a proof oriented problem book,my focus is to solve problems which are applications of theorems.

please provide your suggestions.thank you